# sendgrid make test throws errors

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I'm running node on my vps server. node is at my root, my app.js with node_modules (express, socket.io) are in /home/vps/public_html/

when following github readme for setting up sendgrid i run into trouble:[image: sendgrid github error]

config.js is not live by the sounds of it as when I run sendgrids simple code example if i

a.) refer to config.js by doing:

```
var sendgrid=new SendGrid(user,key);
```

node kills its self because user is not defined.

b.) bypass config.js by doing:

```
var sendgrid=new SendGrid({user:'my_user_name',key:'my_password'});
```

I get console.log(message) of [ 'Permission denied, wrong credentials' ]

here is another image this one is of my public_html structure:[image: public_html]

does any one know how to activate this config.js?

Should I have installed node.js into my public_html in the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there are a few things wrong here:

**1) We have a typo in the README (which has now been updated)**

tl;dr - you should type `npm test` not `make test`

Essentially, you're typing `make test` and make is coming back and saying "Hey, there's no rule for test in the cwd.  It doesn't look like there's anything for me to do. Bye!".  If you look carefully, there is no Makefile in the node library, so there's obviously not going to be any rules.  So make definitely won't work in this case.  What the README should have said is `npm test`.  NPM is the package manager for node and it has a helper method `test` which runs all the tests for a given module.

Also, just to be clear - when you're typing `npm test`, all you are doing is running the tests for the library.  Really this should only be necessary if you're adding features or fixing bugs on the library itself.  If you're trying to use the library to send email, you should read the section titled "Usage".

**2) You have a typo in your code (which is why the other sample didn't work)**

Your code looks like this:

```
var sendgrid = new SendGrid({user:'my_user_name', key:'my_password'});
```

The code sample that we provide looks like this:

```
var sendgrid = new SendGrid(user, key);
```

Notice the difference?  You're passing in a javascript object and we're expecting two discrete string values instead.  The library is interpreting that as your username is "{user:'my_user_name', key:'my_password'}" with no password (because you didn't provide a second parameter).  Instead you should do the following:

```
var sendgrid = new SendGrid("my_user_name", "my_password");
```

Comment: Wow dude they don't call you @Swift for nothing!